# Plotting the volume of an audio file

Tags: audio, charts, sox

Most applications that play sound display its volume graphically.  I need that information (the sound volume as it changes over time) written to a text file so I can plot it myself and use it for analysis purposes.   Thus far I haven't found any application that offers this as a feature, although [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) seems to come close: its --plot function and stat effect offer more advanced functionality.  I'm not sure how to google for it, either.

Can you suggest an easy way to generate such text files, on Linux or Windows?
I can do some programming if that's what it takes.

Answer (score 2):

[Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) has audio processing feature. With Matlab, you can import/export audio data. I have no experience with this functionality of Matlab but the following links may help you.

- [Matlab Programming - Working with Audio and Video
  Data](http://www.kxcad.net/cae_MATLAB/techdoc/matlab_prog/f5-86556.html)
- [Matlab Audio Processing Examples](http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/matlab/)
- [Audio Processing in Matlab](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/307/week1/matlab.html)
- [MATLAB Audio Functions](http://www.johnloomis.org/ece202/labs/sound/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but Matlab is big and I've never used it, so I'm a little afraid of the learning curve.

Comment: Also, Expensive!

Comment: Try Octave instead - it's Matlab-compatible and free

Comment: Wow!  I have no idea Octave could process audio!  Looks like this will be my answer.

http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/octave_263.html

Comment: @pnuts the project finished before I found the time to figure it out, but I bear it in mind for future projects